# "Bad double value" from Google BigQuery even after filtering out NULL safe_cast

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I run the following query (note that it includes a `safe_cast` check):

```
    SELECT
    someField
    FROM some_table
    WHERE someField IS NOT NULL 
    AND safe_cast(someField AS FLOAT64) IS NOT NULL 
    AND CAST(someField AS FLOAT64) > 200.0
    LIMIT 10
```

I get the following result:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "query",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "Bad double value: ; while executing the filter on column 'someField'; File: ':mdb=cloud-dataengine'",
    "reason" : "invalidQuery"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad double value: ; while executing the filter on column 'someField'; File: ':mdb=cloud-dataengine'"
}
```

Shouldn't the `safe_cast(someField AS FLOAT64) IS NOT NULL` have filtered out values that cannot be cast to FLOAT64?  How can I avoid the "bad double value" if not with a safe_cast?

If I remove `AND CAST(someField AS FLOAT64) > 200.0` from the query, I get no complaints, so it must be this comparison that is causing the error... but I don't understand why safe_cast would not have filtered it out.

Comment: Gordon's answer is a good one. You can also force an evaluation order using IF or CASE instead of AND. In this case, though, just using SAFE_CAST is your best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL queries in general don't guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  I would say this is even more true of a modern database like BigQuery than other databases (although it is just as true for most of them).

You seem to understand the solution.  It is simpler to write this anyway:

```
SELECT someField
FROM some_table
WHERE safe_cast(someField AS FLOAT64) > 200.0
LIMIT 10;
```

The `NULL` checks are not needed.  This is saying that the column has a value that can be converted to a float and the value is greater than 200.